# $2\int_0^a f(x)\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}dx\leq b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for $f(0)=0, f(a)=b, f\geq 0, f''\geq 0$.

Tags: definite-integrals, convex-analysis

Let $a,b>0$, $f(0)=0$, $f(a)=b$, $f(x)\geq 0$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. Show that 
$$2\int_0^a f(x)\sqrt{1+(f')^2(x)}\,dx\leq b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

It is easy to see its geometry, the area of $f$ revolved along the $x$-axis. But how to estimate? $f$ is easy by convexity, but $f'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea only as I have no time to work out the details.

Define $F:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
F(t)=f(t)\sqrt{t^{2}+f^{2}(t)}-2\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\sqrt{1+f'^{2}(x)}dx.
$$
Clearly $F$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on
$(0,\infty)$. Moreover, $F(0)=0$. Investigate the derivative $F'(t)$.
If you can prove that $F'(t)\geq0$, then you can conclude that $F$
is increasing and hence $F(t)\geq F(0)=0$. In particular, $F(a)\geq0$.

Comment: Could *you* prove that $F'(t) \ge 0$? I admit that it is not obvious to me, perhaps you can elaborate a bit.